# How to get checked checkbox values from a report - javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, grid

I have a report that list available items with checkbox that users can select their orders by checking the items' checkboxes. All the values of those checked checkbox will be passed to another program for further process. How do I get the values of those checked checkboxes from this report in javascript? Could you please help!
Here is the codes in javascript  http://jsfiddle.net/an2gem2q/9/

```
<table border='0' cellspacing="0" align='center'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <CENTER>
                <input type="submit" name="multclick" value="Start Entry" size="20" onClick="get_check_value();">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='reportTableHeader' align=center colspan=50>Open Orders</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='reportTableHeader'>Line</td>
        <td class="reportTableHeader">I-1</td>
        <td class="reportTableHeader">I-2</td>
        <td class="reportTableHeader">I-3</td>
        <td class="reportTableHeader">I-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='reportTableHeader' valign=top>Lot</td>
        <td class='reportTableData' valign=top align=left>
            <input type=checkbox name=checked-lot value='P101'>
            <input type=text value='P101'>
            <input type=checkbox name=checked-lot value='P102'>
            <input type=text value='P102'>
            <input type=checkbox name=checked-lot value='P103'>
            <input type=text value='P103'>
            <input type=checkbox name=checked-lot value='P107'>
            <input type=text value='P107'>
        </td>
        <td class='reportTableData' valign=top align=left>
            <input type=checkbox name=checked-lot value='P211'>
            <input type=text value='P211'>
            <input type=checkbox name=checked-lot value='P202'>
            <input type=text value='P212'>
            <input type=checkbox name=checked-lot value='P213'>
            <input type=text value='P2103'>
            <input type=checkbox name=checked-lot value='P214'>
            <input type=text value='P214'>
        </td>
        <td class='reportTableData' valign=top align=left>
            <input type=checkbox name=checked-lot value='P321'>
            <input type=text value='P321'>
            <input type=checkbox name=checked-lot value='P322'>
            <input type=text value='P322'>
        </td>
        <td class='reportTableData' valign=top align=left>
            <input type=checkbox name=checked-lot value='P471'>
            <input type=text value='P471'>
            <input type=checkbox name=checked-lot value='P482'>
            <input type=text value='P482'>
            <input type=checkbox name=checked-lot value='P493'>
            <input type=text value='P493'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

function get_check_value()
{
        var c_value = "";
    var c_sum = 0;   
        var c =  line_form.getElementsByTagName('input');
   for (var x = 0; x < c.length; x++) { 
        if (c[x].type == 'checkbox') {
            if(c[x].checked == true){
                           c_sum = c_sum + 1;
               c_value = c_value + c[x].value + ",";

           }
            else{
              c[x].value = "";
           }
           }    
    }
          alert(c_value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the checkboxes on the page and use the `.prop()` in jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

I've added an ID to your Start Entry button called "start". It will push the value of the checkbox into an array, you can go from there. JSFiddle below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#start").click(function () {

        checkedElems = [];
        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                checkedElems.push($(this).attr("value"));
                console.log(checkedElems);
            }

        });


    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/an2gem2q/10/

Edit: Though mentioning `.prop();` I didn't exactly use it in the code, there are variations you can use to get the same result:

```
if ( elem.checked )
if ( $( elem ).prop( "checked" ) )
if ( $( elem ).is( ":checked" ) )
```

Comment: Thank you. How do we see the console.log or the results from the jsfiddle?

Comment: If you press F12 in your web browser and go to console you can see the output. Chrome has the best console in my opinion.

Comment: You're very welcome Mary. Can you upvote or mark it as completed?